# Xamarin Studio Addin - New Solution Extension Point?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, add-in, xamarin-studio

How do I add a new entry to the "New Solution" panel in Xamarin Studio in an addin?

Comment: I also suggest you to come to #monodevelop irc channel on irc.gimp.org or https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/MonoDevelop (just me for now :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project.addin.xml you have to add [/MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates extension path entries.](https://github.com/DavidKarlas/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework/blob/c71e5a458b41efd607f680659d483a92f9fc31e8/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework.addin.xml#L522-L525)
And then also add [new project template file](https://github.com/DavidKarlas/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework/blob/3a2fb94671652c7241c53f4d858f0c3fbf2ceda3/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework/Templates/MicroFrameworkConsoleProject.xpt.xml) to your [AddIn project resources](https://github.com/DavidKarlas/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework/blob/b5c77bf54a385e42c354db526b6516a6e1bc6db8/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework/MonoDevelop.MicroFramework.csproj#L125-L127)(simply add file to your project and mark it as EmbededResource). Make sure resource names in project and /MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates match.